# How to select an object in canvas wpf

Tags: wpf, canvas, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I am dropping ListBox items (items here are textbox, checkbox, radio buttons when user drops onto canvas we are creating controls dynamic and adding to canvas) to Canvas. Now when user clicks on any item in the canvas, want to show properties on that control.
How to get the selected control from the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

To get UI element under mouse on click you can perform hit testing. In XAML define `MouseDown` event handler:

```
<Canvas Mouse.MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown">
```

and implement it:

```
private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = sender as Canvas;
    if (canvas == null)
        return;

    HitTestResult hitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(canvas, e.GetPosition(canvas));
    var element = hitTestResult.VisualHit;

    // do something with element
}
```